# Trigger a click sender in another method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, event-handling, buttonclick

I have the following codes that is the button on and off:

```
private void OnActivity_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as Button).Content.Equals("On"))
    {
        (sender as Button).Content = "Off";
    }
    else 
    {
        (sender as Button).Content = "On";
    }
}
```

I have another method named `protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)`

How can I call the sender as Button of OnActivity_Click into another method ? I need to trigger **On** and **Off** then **On** again in the navigation method. Someone help me pls ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside OnNavigatedTo you can use the button reference. For example:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    OnActivity_Click(this.btn1, null);
}
```

Your button here has the name "btn1" (set it in xaml).

Comment: May I know what is the null ? I had the System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs needed as I saw it become to the null the second time I trigger the button

Comment: I have to Off the Button then On again. The Off is working fine, but during the second trigger of this method the e is null which by default is {System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs}

Comment: If you don't use the event args, you can send a null (which is the "0" value for every reference type). If you need it, instead of null you can send a new RoutedEventArgs() and add what data you need. The event args is specific to the event and contains additional data. When you click a button you have some data in EventArgs passed in by the framework. In OnNavigatedTo you have other data. What exactly are you using from RoutedEventArgs that you need ?

Comment: I have this method inside calling another method that is httpRequest(something), when the method run the first time, at the end of the method brackets "}" It can navigate to the private void InfoResponseHandler(IAsyncResult asyncResult), However the second time the button is trigger with the e is null, it can't work. How can I make the System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs to appear inside the e instead?

Comment: You can use something like OnActivity_Click(this.btn1, new RoutedEventArgs()); But as long as I don't know which property of e is used (because if it is null, you can't access a property) I cannot guarantee that your code will do what you want.

Comment: OnActivity_Click(this.btn1, new RoutedEventArgs() { PropertyYouUseFromE = "Value that you expect"} );

Answer (score 1):

Give name to the button in xaml like `x:name="btn"`

and then use it in `OnNavigatedTo` method like this,

```
btn.content="On";
```